# Dynamically compare row, cell by cell, then go to next row and repeat (Large Range)

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, compare, excel-2010

I am trying to compare two large sets of data and highlight the cells that do not match one another. If a row has a cell that is different then copy and paste that row to a separate sheet.
Also I need it to be dynamic because the data sets can change columns and/or rows.

For Example:
To compare B2 to E2, C2 to F2, highlight the differences and copy paste row to another sheet. Then move down to the next row and compare B3 to E3, C3 to F3 and keep looping till complete.

[image]

Currently, I have the following code, but its comparing one cell in the first range area to the second range area and then it moves to the next cell in the first  range area and repeats. I need it to compare each cell respectively.

```
Sub Compare()

Dim rangeToUse As Range, singleArea As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, I As Integer, J As Integer

Set rangeToUse = Selection
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

If Selection.Areas.Count <= 1 Then
      MsgBox "Please select more than one area."
    Else
        rangeToUse.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
        For Each singleArea In rangeToUse.Areas
            singleArea.BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThin
        Next singleArea
        For I = 1 To rangeToUse.Areas.Count
            For J = I + 1 To rangeToUse.Areas.Count
                For Each cell1 In rangeToUse.Areas(I)
                    For Each cell2 In rangeToUse.Areas(J)
                        If cell1.Value <> cell2.Value Then
                            cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                            cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                        End If
                    Next cell2
                Next cell1
            Next J
        Next I
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're comparing each cell in the first range to *every* cell in the second range, which, I don't believe, is what you want to do. I'm also assuming that you want to compare `area(1)` to `area(2)`, not `area(1)` to `area(1)..area(n)`, then `area(2)` to `area(1)..area(n)`.

```
Sub Compare()

Dim rangeToUse As Range, singleArea As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim I As Integer, J As Integer

Set rangeToUse = Selection
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

If Selection.Areas.Count <= 1 Then
      MsgBox "Please select more than one area."
    Else
        rangeToUse.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
        For Each singleArea In rangeToUse.Areas
            singleArea.BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThin
        Next singleArea
        'Areas.count - 1 will avoid trying to compare
        ' Area(count) to the non-existent area(count+1)
        For I = 1 To rangeToUse.Areas.Count - 1
            For Each cell1 In rangeToUse.Areas(I)
                'I+1 gets you the NEXT area
                set Cell2 = rangeToUse.areas(I+1).Cells(cell1.row, Cell1.Column)
                if cell1.value <> Cell2.value then
                    cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    Cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    Cell1.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=DestSheet.DestRow
                End If
            Next cell1
        Next I
End If

End Sub
```

This line:
`set Cell2 = rangeToUse.areas(I+1).Cells(cell1.row, Cell1.Column)`
may need some tweaking to get the offset correct, but I believe that will get you in the correct direction. I *believe* that `cell1.Row` and `cell1.Column` will give you a relative row/column in the range, but I'm not 100% certain of that.

Comment: Thank you @FreeMan
Yes, `cell1.Row` and `cell1.Column` give relative range so the code tweaking i had to use was : 
`Set cell2 = rangeToUse.Areas(I + 1).Cells(cell1.row - 1, cell1.Column - 1)`
Also, do you know how I can flag rows that have had cells highlighted and copied to another spreadsheet?

Comment: Glad that was on track! You can try `rangeToUse.EntireRow`, I think that should do the trick.

Comment: @JFro777, did `.EntireRow` do what you wanted? If so, I'll edit it in to the answer to make it easier for others to find.

Comment: Im not sure how to implement it. @FreeMan

Comment: @JFro777, take a look at the line I added starting with `cell1.EntireRow.Copy`. You will need to `Dim DestSheet as Worksheet` and `Set` it to the worksheet where you want these to be pasted. Then I'd suggest `Dim DestRow as Integer` and set its value to the row where you want the first one to be pasted. Each time you paste, increment `DestRow` by 1 to always have the next row ready to go.

Comment: The code is getting hung up on the "`.DestRow`" part on the line you suggested and i have Dim'ed as you suggested as well. The error i am getting is:
"Method or data member not found"

Comment: `.DestRow` is not a valid property of a worksheet. You'll have to keep track of where on your destination worksheet you are (`DestRow` from my comment above) and specify the `.Range` on `DestSheet` where you are pasting. The use of `DestRow` was simply a place holder - I guess I wasn't very clear in that.